# $_POST , FORM and PhP

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have read many questions on this theme but didn't find answer.
I have an error `Notice: Undefined index: searchText in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\lib\search.php on line 5` Don't know why...

HTML form:

```
<div id="search" class="fleft">
        <form name="tsearch" action="lib/search.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="searchText" placeholder="Search tweet!">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and part of PhP script where I'm sending but don't getting data

Full sript.
    UPDATED:

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    //session_start();

        if (isset($_POST['searchText'])){
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_REQUEST); echo '</pre>';
            $query = "SELECT u.nickname, t.text, t.pubdate FROM 111212_tweets t INNER JOIN 111212_users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id WHERE t.text LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchText'] . "%' ORDER BY t.pubdate DESC";
           $_SESSION['searchQuery'] = $query;
             header('Location: ../main.php');

        }else {
            $query = "SELECT u.nickname, t.text, t.pubdate FROM 111212_tweets t INNER JOIN 111212_users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id ORDER BY t.pubdate DESC";
          $_SESSION['searchQuery'] = $query;

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Are you checking to see if your form has been submitted, before you check `if ($_POST['searchText'])`?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['searchText']))`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `isset()` to see if the variable is set:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchText']))
```

If you want to see if it contains a value (i.e. is not empty), use `empty()` with it as well:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchText']) && !empty($_POST['searchText']))
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 13 seconds :)

Comment: +1 for fast nice response. BTW if using `!empty` you won't need `isset`

Comment: thank you. But i think that I didn't ask correctly, I know, that I don't have anythning i variable, but how to get???

Comment: If someone submits the form with a value in the input field named "searchText" you will get the value in that variable

Comment: mm, maybe don't work a query, which I use...hmmmm... Please check it.    I have updated question

Answer (score 3):

To check if an index exists, you have to use `isset()`, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['searchText'])){
     //do some stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@John Conde is right. Just to add something...A notice is not an error, The server is just telling you that your variable is not set.

It's a good practice to check the variables (isset()) but if you don't want to and are a little lazy, you can set the error_reporting for just mark the errors
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php